# Download .pdf file to R, getting error message

Tags: r, pdf

I'm having trouble download a .pdf from the internet into Rstudio. I would like to analyse the .pdf using the `pdftools` package. I have a directory called `files` that I want the .pdf to go to. I'm using this code.

```
download.file('https://www2.gov.scot/Resource/Doc/352649/0118638.pdf', 'files')
```

I get this error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In download.file("https://www2.gov.scot/Resource/Doc/352649/0118638.pdf",  :
  URL https://www2.gov.scot/Resource/Doc/352649/0118638.pdf: cannot open destfile 'files', reason 'Is a directory'
2: In download.file("https://www2.gov.scot/Resource/Doc/352649/0118638.pdf",  :
  download had nonzero exit status
```

Is there way to get around this message?

Comment: Read the Error carefully, `'files'` is a directory. Try `download.file('https://www2.gov.scot/Resource/Doc/352649/0118638.pdf', 'myPdf.pdf')` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `destfile` has to be the filename (**not the directory name**) for the downloaded file.

For example, if we were to download the file above and save it as "Commission.pdf" in the `files` folder we would do the following:

```
download.file(url='https://www2.gov.scot/Resource/Doc/352649/0118638.pdf',
 destfile="files/Commission.pdf")
```

You're passing in `file` to the `destfile`, which prompts R to throw the error warning that the argument you specified *is a directory*.

Comment: Thanks, I did make that mistake. But I'm still getting the same error message. It seems to be with the url as this link `https://www.gov.scot/binaries/content/documents/govscot/publications/publication/2011/06/commission-future-delivery-public-services/documents/0118638-pdf/0118638-pdf/govscot%3Adocument` to the same .pdf seems to work without issues.

Comment: Nope @elliot I'm quite sure it works. I fired up an R console and run exactly the code above and got the pdf downloaded

Comment: Can you try the http version instead? Replace the value to the `url` argument to `http://www2.gov.scot/Resource/Doc/352649/0118638.pdf` ?

Comment: I will try. I'm using a RStudio server. So it might be an issue with that?

Comment: To fully troubleshoot that, I would try to specify different methods, `download.file(url='...', destfile='...', method='auto')`. "auto", "wget", "lynx" "cp" and "socket" are all possible options. If you suspect it's an issue there's where I would start with the troubleshooting. Maybe open a second question on SO for that (as well as your session info)?

Answer (score 0):

You miss the function assignature. It is

```
download.file(url, destfile, ...)
```

Therefore, when you're using `download.file('https://www2.gov.scot/Resource/Doc/352649/0118638.pdf', 'files')`, you are downloading the file `https://www2.gov.scot/Resource/Doc/352649/0118638.pdf` and saving it with the name `files`.

What you need to do is to modify the second argument to encopass the complete file path. It can be something like this:

```
download.file('https://www2.gov.scot/Resource/Doc/352649/0118638.pdf', 'files/0118638.pdf')
```